# (Android) Explicit Intent Error

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_me);


    button1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextActivity);
                }
            } 
    );

}
```

Hi Guys, I'm having an error when declaring / creating a new instance of the Intent,

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
```

It says cannot resolve constructor Intent....
What is wrong?

Sorry for the long post, hope you guys will let me know soon. 
Thanks!!

Comment: you should learn java's basics:  like what does `this`  means

Comment: I did learn java, but the android developers official page said to insert the current object which "this" refers to, this is what I did...

Comment: No you didn't learn ... obviously in anonymous class `this` means instance of this class not outer class

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextActivity);
                }
            } 
    );
```

and make sure you have to declare `NextActivity.class` in `AndroidManifest.xml`